# How to list Swift types that conform to protocol using reflection?

Tags: swift, reflection

How does one list types that conform to a protocol for purely Swift based types (i.e. no `@objc` annotation involved)? I was hoping that a reflection API that allows for this would be provided in the Swift standard library.

Just to be doubly sure, I am aware of the more specialised case of Objective-C or @objc annotated Swift classes conforming to a protocol solvable with Objective-C runtime APIs: [How to list all classes conforming to protocol in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415028/how-to-list-all-classes-conforming-to-protocol-in-swift) – what I am after is the same for an arbitrary Swift type that may be a struct, enum or a class.

Here is my feeble failed attempt at using the [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html) API for the purpose:

```
protocol Derpable {
    func derp();
}

extension Derpable {
    func derp() {
        print("Herp derp.")
    }
}

enum E: Derpable { }

class C: Derpable { }

struct S: Derpable { }

print(Mirror(reflecting: Derpable.self).children.count) // prints "0\n"
```

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible with pure Swift (yet)

Comment: Yep, this still gives the same 0 with Xcode 7.3 :-(

Comment: New reflection APIs are coming, most probably after 3.0 is out

Comment: Any news regarding that question? `Mirror(reflecting: Derpable.self).children.count` still gives `0` in Swift 3.0.2 =(

Comment: Nope. The Swift-users list may be a good spot to ask about this: https://lists.swift.org/mailman/listinfo/swift-users ? I have not really followed the discussion recently to know if completing the reflection API is on their roadmap anytime soon.