# Does Swift provide an API for creating Dynamic Proxies Like Java does with Reflection Proxy API?

Tags: swift, dynamic, reflection, proxy

I am trying to create a proxy generator for Swift. I have used the Java Reflections API for proxy generation but can't seem to find anything related for Swift.

Answer (score 0):

See [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html) in the stdlib for a reflection API.

Mirror still has a lot of issues by Swift 2.2, for instance [querying protocol conformance fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125708/how-to-list-swift-types-that-conform-to-protocol-using-reflection), as does reflecting enums with no associated values (only ones with associated values appear to have the necessary runtime type information accessible in current versions of Swift?).

Some external resources on it:

1. [The Swift Reflection API and what you can do with it](https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/)
2. [NSHipster of MirrorType](http://nshipster.com/mirrortype/) (note that this is an older post and refers to the type with its older MirrorType name.