# Confused about type judgement in swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

Met the same issue with [Swift 3.1 deprecates initialize(). How can I achieve the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824541/swift-3-1-deprecates-initialize-how-can-i-achieve-the-same-thing), @Jordan Smith 's solution is very impressive, then i was interested in the implement, but met some troubles in practice, here are some key codes, see the comments, why the log function in `UIViewController` was not called, it conforms protocol; why `UIViewController` was caught but `T == UIViewController.self` is `false`:

```
protocol Conscious {
    static func awake()
}

/** extension */
extension UIViewController: Conscious {
    static func awake() {
        if self == UIViewController.self {
            print(self, #function)     // never came here, but seems should come
        }
    }
}

/** main */
private static let _operation: Void = {
    let typeCount = Int(objc_getClassList(nil, 0))
    let types = UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass?>.allocate(capacity: typeCount)
    let autoreleasingTypes = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass?>(types)
    objc_getClassList(autoreleasingTypes, Int32(typeCount))

    for index in 0 ..< typeCount {
        (types[index] as? Conscious.Type)?.awake()

        let T = types[index]!
        let vc = UIViewController()
        print(T, vc.isKind(of: T), T == UIViewController.self)
        /*
          Strange things:
          UIResponder true false
          UIViewController true false(why is false)
          UISearchController false false
         */
    }

    types.deallocate(capacity: typeCount)
}()
```

Comment: What are your questions?

Comment: @rmaddy sorry, see the comments in codes

Comment: OK, so again, what are you questions?

Comment: Why the log function in UIViewController was not called, it conforms protocol; why UIViewController was catched but `T == UIViewController.self` is false

Comment: You should use `===`-operator instead

Answer (score 0):

Well, It looks like UIViewController's swift extensions are not visible using `objc` methods.
So here is my solution based on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415028/how-to-list-all-classes-conforming-to-protocol-in-swift).

First you need to mark `Conscious`-protocol with `@objc` keyword.

```
@objc protocol Conscious {
    static func awake()
}
```

Then you need to use `class_conformsToProtocol`-function.

```
let type = types[index]!
if class_conformsToProtocol(type, Conscious.self) {
    let item = type as! Conscious.Type
    item.awake()
}
```